# How to substitute username/connection string in SSH config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I'm trying to configure SSH to log into multiple hosts behind a CyberArk PSM SSH proxy.

I'm using OpenSSH v. 9.4.

I can connect directly like this:

```
ssh -i <key> <user>@<cybearkuser>%<domain>@<remotehost>@<proxyaddress>
```

The only variable here is `remotehost`, so I want to configure SSH to automatically replace it in the long connection string, when I just type `ssh remotehost`.

I first made my SSH config like so:

```
Host abc-*remotehost
    Hostname user@user%%domain.com@%h@proxy.domain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

*Note that `%h` expands to the host, and `%%` is just a regular `%`.*

But now, when I just do `ssh abc-123.remotehost`, it seems SSH interprets the whole line as a host (understandably), and complains it cannot resolve it.
It correctly substituted the hostname into the long string, though.

I assume everything before the final `@` is supposed to be the SSH username, so I thought I could just do this:

```
Host abc-*remotehost
    Hostname proxy.domain.com
    User user@user%%domain.com@%h
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

But that doesn't work, as these substitution tokens only work on specific keywords, and not `User` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#TOKENS)).

Note that if I just put the whole `<user>@<cybearkuser>%<domain>@<remotehost>` part in statically as `User`, it works fine, but I really want to substitute it to avoid repeating this for 30+ hosts.

Is there some other trick I can try?